# Concatenate table with a specific order

Tags: cat

I would like to concatenate the following table:

```
A
B
C
D
E
...
```

I am currently using:

```
find "PATH" name "*.txt" -exec cat {} + >> "PATH/output.txt"
```

My problem is that this command concatenate from A to X; indeed I would like to concatenate from X to A. Does anyone knows how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sticking a `sort` in there:

```
find "PATH" -name "*.txt" -print0 | sort -rz | xargs -0 cat >  "PATH/output.txt"
```

And note that, given the same `PATH`, `output.txt` might be included in this, so the results might not be what you expected.

Comment: exactly what I was asking for. Thank you so much!